# Can't make a dialog box to check confirmation points

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alertdialog

There I can't write code to simple dialog. I don't understand how to solve this problem.

```
void _showSimpleDialog() {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: Text('Do you want delete point?'),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                Future<void> deleteUser(BuildContext context) async {
                  var res = await _apiClient.deleteAccount();
                  if (res == 200) {
                    await Navigator.of(context)
                        .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('auth', (route) => false);
                    await deactivateUser();
                  }
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Yes'),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                _dismissDialog();
              },
              child: const Text('No'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The dialog accepts a `BuildContext`. So you'll have to provide it.
2. The dialog has a return value of `Future<T?>`. so you'll have to specify the return type as `Future<void>`

Your function should look like this:

```dart
Future<void> _showSimpleDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: Text('Do you want delete point?'),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                Future<void> deleteUser(BuildContext context) async {
                  // var res = await _apiClient.deleteAccount();
                  // if (res == 200) {
                  await Navigator.of(context)
                      .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('auth', (route) => false);
                  // await deactivateUser();
                  // }
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Yes'),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                // _dismissDialog();
              },
              child: const Text('No'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
}
```

And when you call it, you should provide a `BuildContext`:

```dart
_showSimpleDialog(context);
```

---

Complete runnable example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            child: Text(
              'Click Me',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _showSimpleDialog(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> _showSimpleDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: Text('Do you want delete point?'),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                Future<void> deleteUser(BuildContext context) async {
                  // var res = await _apiClient.deleteAccount();
                  // if (res == 200) {
                  await Navigator.of(context)
                      .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('auth', (route) => false);
                  // await deactivateUser();
                  // }
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Yes'),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                // _dismissDialog();
              },
              child: const Text('No'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
}
```